# verify that my repo it's in fact a github repo URL in Go

Tags: regex, go, package, goland

Is there a method in Go to verify that a repo type string is in fact an actual Github repo URL?

I'm running this code that clones a repo, but before I run exec.Command("git", "clone", repo) and i want to make sure that repo is valid.

```
    package utils

    import (
        "os/exec"
    )

    //CloneRepo clones a repo lol
    func CloneRepo(args []string) {

        //repo URL
        repo := args[0]

        //verify that is an actual github repo URL

        //Clones Repo
        exec.Command("git", "clone", repo).Run()

    }
```

Comment: I've made a minor edit to your question so that it is not asking for package recommendations, which would make it off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using the [`net`](https://golang.org/pkg/net), [`net/url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url), and [`strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) packages.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func isGitHubURL(input string) bool {
    u, err := url.Parse(input)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    host := u.Host
    if strings.Contains(host, ":") { 
        host, _, err = net.SplitHostPort(host)
        if err != nil {
            return false
        }
    }
    return host == "github.com"
}

func main() {
    urls := []string{
        "https://github.com/foo/bar",
        "http://github.com/bar/foo",
        "http://github.com.evil.com",
        "http://github.com:8080/nonstandard/port",
        "http://other.com",
        "not a valid URL",
    }
    for _, url := range urls {
        fmt.Printf("URL: \"%s\", is GitHub URL: %v\n", url, isGitHubURL(url))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
URL: "https://github.com/foo/bar", is GitHub URL: true
URL: "http://github.com/bar/foo", is GitHub URL: true
URL: "http://github.com.evil.com", is GitHub URL: false
URL: "http://github.com:8080/nonstandard/port", is GitHub URL: true
URL: "http://other.com", is GitHub URL: false
URL: "not a valid URL", is GitHub URL: false
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AG3nTqbCmdy)

Comment: `strings.Index(u.Host, "github.com") == 0` reports false negatives for `github.com.evil.net`. Use [net.SplitHostPort](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#SplitHostPort) and a normal string comparison to ignore the port.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dedicated [git url parser](https://github.com/armosec/go-git-url) as following:

```
package utils

import (
    "os/exec"

    giturl "github.com/armosec/go-git-url"
)

func isGitURL(repo string) bool {
    _, err := giturl.NewGitURL(repo) // parse URL, returns error if none git url

    return err == nil
}

//CloneRepo clones a repo lol
func CloneRepo(args []string) {

    //repo URL
    repo := args[0]

    //verify that is an actual github repo URL
    if !isGitURL(repo) {
        // return
    }

    //Clones Repo
    exec.Command("git", "clone", repo).Run()
}
```

This will give you the advantage of not only validating if it is a git repo, but you can run more validations so as owner (`GetOwner()`), repo (`GetRepo()`) etc.